# Show that all codings can be transformed into codings with alphabet $\Sigma=\{a\}$

Tags: coding-theory

I have trouble understanding this exercise, especially since we never defined what it means for a coding to be 'transformed' into another one.

It seems to me as if the question is just:
Can you count just by listing ones (or $a$'s)? In this case the answer is yes, I assume.
Or to put it slightly differently: Is there a bijection between all words over some finite alphabet $\Sigma$ and all words over $\{a\}$? Again, I think of course there is, as by listing all words in $\Sigma$ one after another one is essentially counting them up, so they correspond to the list $\{a, aa, aaa, ..\}$.

Do you think this is the right direction or am I completely misunderstanding the whole point?
If the former, what is really meant by 'showing' this, I mean what do they expect to read, there isn't really much one can say about it, or so it seems to me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how exactly they define `coding` and what the exact context of this exercise is. But from the limited context which you present here, your line of thought seems correct to me. I cannot be sure though.